# How to split (chunk) a Ruby array into parts of X elements?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array

```
foo = %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

How can I split or "chunk" this into smaller arrays?

```
class Array
  def chunk(size)
    # return array of arrays
  end
end

foo.chunk(3)
# => [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
```

Answer (score 403, accepted):

Take a look at [Enumerable#each_slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice):

```
foo.each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"], ["10"]]
```

Comment: So simple, so ruby. I used `t = []; d.each_slice(3) {|s| t << s}`, ... why didn't I just try #to_a, thanks man.

Comment: Nice. I used something similar to `foo.each_slice(3).each_with_index { |f, i| puts "#{f}, #{i}" }` in order to work through the array in slices (or "chunks").

Comment: If array size doesn't divide evenly into the number of chunks, is there a way to merge the remainder chunk with the previous one? So in your example, `["10"]` would be merged with `["7", "8", "9"]` to make the last chunk `["7", "8", "9", "10"]`?

Answer (score 62):

If you're using rails you can also use [in_groups_of](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of):

```
foo.in_groups_of(3)
```

Comment: note that in_groups_of uses each_slice and also performs "padding" if you don't need the padding, then go with each_slice

Comment: Actually, you can pass a second parameter to in_groups_of, telling it what to pad with, and if that is false, it doesn't pad. So, no need for each_slice either way.

Comment: Be careful. It makes empty element for `nil`. For example, if you makes `arr = [0,1,2,3,4]` with `in_groups_of(3)`, then its result is `[[0,1,2],[3,4,nil]]`. In some case, it can make some troubles.

Comment: @Penguin if you use `foo.in_groups_of(2, false)` it won't pad with `nil` elements

Comment: This is Rails only...

Comment: @dawg What else could `If you're using rails` mean? lol