# Split an array into some sub-arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split (chunk) a Ruby array into parts of X elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699584/how-to-split-chunk-a-ruby-array-into-parts-of-x-elements)

I would like to split an array into an array of sub-arrays.

For example,

```
big_array = (0...6).to_a
```

How can we cut this big array into an array of arrays (of a max length of 2 items) such as:

```
arrays = big_array.split_please(2)
```

Where...

```
arrays # => [ [0, 1],
              [2, 3],
              [4, 5] ]
```

Note:
I ask this question, 'cause in order to do it, I'm currently coding like this:

```
arrays = [
           big_array[0..1],
           big_array[2..3],
           big_array[4..5]
         ]
```

...which is so ugly. And very unmaintainable code, when `big_array.length > 100`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `#each_slice` method on the array

```
big_array = (0..20).to_a
array = big_array.each_slice(2).to_a
puts array # [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], [20]]
```

Comment: how is it not the same as my `slice`? :)

Comment: Thanks, just perfect. I'm gonna learn more seriously the Ruby's API o_o;

Answer (score 6):

check out the [slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice):

```
big_array.each_slice( 2 ).to_a
```