# Wrapping 3 results in a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I need to wrap 3 results in separate divs.
I am returning the results with a basic query:

```
@items = Item.all
```

but in the view, I need to list the results in blocks of 3 :

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>    
<div>
  <p>Result 1</p>
  <p>Result 2</p>
  <p>Result 3</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Result 4</p>
  <p>Result 5</p>
  <p>Result 6</p>
</div>
```

etc...

Any help appreciated from a ROR noob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% @items.each_slice(3) do |chunk| %>
<div>
    <% chunk.each do |item| %>
        <p><%= item %></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

(Related to: [How to split (chunk) a Ruby array into parts of X elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699584/how-to-split-chunk-a-ruby-array-into-parts-of-x-elements))