# Take three items from an array at a time and loop?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple array of records from my database.

I'm building a responsive layout and I need to place only three items in each `<div class="row"></div>`.

How can I loop over the collection and take three items at a time to output one `.row` div, and each of the elements within?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a.each_slice(3) {|e| p "<div>#{e}</div>"}
```

See this question for more detail about `each_slice`: [How to split (chunk) a Ruby array into parts of X elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699584/how-to-split-chunk-a-ruby-array-into-parts-of-x-elements)

An example:

```
<% for member_row in @members.each_slice(3).to_a %>
  <div class="row">

    <% for member in member_row %>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><%= member.name %></p>
      </div>  

    <% end %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit your answer with a simple view example for completeness sake.

Comment: @Serg don't use `for` in ruby, 99.9% of the case you don't need it, just do `@members.each_slice(3) do |member_row|` and `member_row.each do |member|`

Comment: @Serg, it's improper to add code to other people's answers. *IF* you have an example of what you did, you're free to append it to your question along with a little text explaining that's how you used it, but consider other people's answers sacred. Tweaking grammar and spelling, and even the formatting of code for readability, are acceptable.

Comment: @theTinMan: Been using this site for years, first time I've heard of that silly rule.

Comment: It's considered an inappropriate edit. If you did it with a lower rating the normal juried-review process would very likely have rejected it.