# Splitting array in three different arrays of maximum three elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

I have an array:

```
array = [12, 13, 14, 18, 17, 19, 30, 23]
```

I need to split this array into arrays of maximum three elements each:

```
[12, 13, 14] [18, 17, 19] [30, 23]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This question has already been asked.  Here is a link to it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699584/how-to-split-chunk-a-ruby-array-into-parts-of-x-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...
Using  `Enumerable#each_slice` to slice array x value

```
array  = [12, 13, 14, 18, 17, 19, 30, 23]
array.each_slice(3)
array.each_slice(3).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Enumerable#each_slice:

```
foo.each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"], ["10"]]
```

If you're using rails you can also use in_groups_of:

```
foo.in_groups_of(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

By this time, I hope you got your answer. If you are using **Rails**, you can go with [`in_groups`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Array/in_groups), you won't have to call `to_a` explicitly then :

```
array.in_groups(3)
# => [[12, 13, 14], [18, 17, 19], [30, 23, nil]]

array.in_groups(3, false)
# => [[12, 13, 14], [18, 17, 19], [30, 23]]
```

One more **advantage** of using `in_groups` is, you can preserve the array size (strictly). It will `fill_with` = `nil` to maintain the array size.