# Jekyll - split an array into subarrays given n items

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

This question has been addressed within the context of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) and [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699584/how-to-split-chunk-a-ruby-array-into-parts-of-x-elements) by this community, but how would you accomplish the same thing using Jekyll / Liquid templating? Hypothetically, something along the lines of:

```
{% assign subarrays = array | split_items_by: 3 %}
```

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to create multidimensional arrays in Liquid, would be the same to process an array by chunks of 3?

Answer (score 0):

Verbose code :

```
{% assign subArraySize = 3 %}

{% assign myArray = "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven" | split: "," %}
myArray = {{ myArray | inspect }}

{% assign multiArray = "" | split: "/" %}
multiArray = {{ multiArray | inspect }}

{% for element in myArray %}
  looping in myArray - forloop.index = {{ forloop.index }}

  {% assign reminder = forloop.index | modulo: subArraySize %}
  reminder : {{ reminder | inspect }}

  {% if reminder == 1 %}
  create a new empty sub array
  {% assign subArray = "" | split: "/" %}
  subArray = {{ subArray | inspect }}
  {% endif %}

  push current element in subArray
  {% assign subArray = subArray | push: element %}
  subArray = {{ subArray | inspect }}

  {% if reminder == 0 or forloop.last %}
  push subArray in multiArray if subarray length is
    {% assign multiArray = multiArray | push: subArray %}
  multiArray = {{ multiArray | inspect }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for subArray in multiArray %}
 subArray :{{ subArray | inspect }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you already have ruby code available, you can write a [tag plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags)